# How update entity field from Controller?

Tags: security, symfony

I have Entity which name is Task. And there are fields, setters, getters. This Entity working fine. From ROLE_ADMIN, I can update, create etc... But now I have Solving controller...and there in index action from ROLE_USER I want show form which should update field 'status' in Task Entity. How I can do this ?

Can I just give accsess in security file for ROLE_USER to update Task ? If yes please give me example. I try this:

```
- { path: ^/task/edit, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
- { path: ^/task/edit, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first line with ROLE_ADMIN and it should work. When using the default configuration ROLE_ADMIN extends ROLE_USER, that means if a route is set to be accessible by ROLE_USER its automatically also accessible by ROLE_ADMIN.

In your configuration, the route with ROLE_ADMIN is matched first and therefore you should get a 403 error and your second route will never be used.

If you want the rest of the actions to be secured and only edit to be accessible do it like this:

```
- { path: ^/task/edit, roles: ROLE_USER }
- { path: ^/task, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

That way the more specific route /task/edit checks for user, whereas all other routes starting with /task require ROLE_ADMIN.

Comment: but then all can put in url 'localhos/app.dev/task' and see the tasks.

Comment: @JohnyOggy I changed my answer accordingly. From your example I assumed, that you only care about /task/edit. You could just as well put each route in the list, e.g. `path: ^/task$`, `path: ^/task/create` and so on, but that might be hard to maintain.

Comment: when I type app_dev.php/task/1/edit I get Access Denied.
Thank you for helping

Comment: my security file now:
- { path: ^/task/edit, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/task/new, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/task/show, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/task, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

Comment: Shouldn't it be `app_dev.php/task/edit/1`, i.e. first the action then the parameters? `app_dev.php/task/1/edit` is not matched by my example and with the routes you posted the last (^/task with ROLE_ADMIN) should match, therefore you should get Access Denied.